# AngularJs: $http.post always return 404 error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am currently trying to develop a simple angular js application.
I am trying to post data from client to web api.
However, I am getting 404 error when I fire post request from angular app.

Below is my post request,

```
 $http.post('/api/LoadApi/', jsonData).then(function (result) {
                console.log(result.data);
            })
           .catch(function (error) {
           });
```

where jsonData is a valid json data.

My web api code is this,

```
public class LoadApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoadData(object dataToLoad)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);

        return response;
    }
}
```

My web api route config is this,

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
                name: "DefaultApi",
                routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{dataToLoad}"
            );
```

However, when I run the code, it throws an error

***Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found.
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
Requested URL: /api/LoadApi/***

***Can anyone point what is the problem with the above code?***

It says there is some problem with url. The url generated is http://localhost:14154/api/LoadApi/ which looks correct.

Comment: your route template couldn't work, because it doesn't define which action on the controller you want to match.

Comment: also, you don't use `POST` to send data on the URL string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your route definition and how you are trying to send data to your controller method. I would recommend using attribute based routing. In your Web API controller do this:

```
[RoutePrefix("api/LoadApi")]
public class LoadApiController : ApiController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("loadData")]
    public HttpResponseMessage LoadData(object dataToLoad)
    {
        var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Created);
        return response;
    }
}
```

Change the `Application_Start()` method in `Global.asax.cs` to this:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    GlobalConfiguration.Configure(WebApiConfig.Register);
}
```

Make sure `WebApiConfig.cs` in `App_Start` has a `Register()` method like this:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
}
```

And finally change your `$http.post` call to this:

```
$http.post('/api/LoadApi/loadData', jsonData).then([...]);
```